# Replace special XML characters in PL/SQL

Tags: c#, sql, xml, oracle

I'm using SQL XMLAgg function that returns me special characters. I need to replace them with "regular" characters, i.e, replace `&lt;` to `<` etc..

I have been tried to use `UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE` but I'm getting  error

> ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB or BLOC to RAW conversion (actual: 10030, maximum: 4000)

My query looks like : `UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFEREENCE(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, comments)).extract('//text()').getclobval))`

How can I did it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, comments)).extract('//text()')), DBMS_XMLGEN.ENTITY_DECODE) ` (not tested).

Comment: Should use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) and System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string)

Answer (score 0):

Process the CLOB in chunks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UNESCAPE_XML(xml_clob IN CLOB) RETURN CLOB IS
DECLARE

    clob_UNESCAPE CLOB;    
    read_offset INTEGER := 1;
    ClobLen INTEGER;
    amount INTEGER := 3000;

BEGIN

    ClobLen := DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(xml_clob);
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(clob_UNESCAPE, TRUE);
    LOOP
        EXIT WHEN read_offset > ClobLen;
        stringBuffer := UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFEREENCE(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(xml_clob , amount, read_offset));
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(clob_UNESCAPE, LENGTH(stringBuffer), stringBuffer);
        read_offset := read_offset + amount;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN clob_UNESCAPE;
END;
```