# Oracle remove html from clob fields

Tags: sql, oracle, blob, html-parsing

I have a simple function to convert html blob to plain text

```
 FUNCTION HTML_TO_TEXT(html IN CLOB) RETURN CLOB
 IS v_return CLOB;
   BEGIN     
select utl_i18n.unescape_reference(regexp_replace(html, '<.+?>', ' ')) INTO v_return from dual;
return (v_return);
    END;
```

called in that way:

```
SELECT A, B, C, HTML_TO_TEXT(BLobField) FROM t1
```

all works fine until BlobFields contains more than 4000 character, then i got

```
ORA-01704: string literal too long
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

i try to avoud string inside function using variables but nothing changes:

```
FUNCTION HTML_TO_TEXT(html IN CLOB) RETURN CLOB
 IS v_return CLOB;
 "stringa" CLOB;
   BEGIN 
    SELECT regexp_replace(html, '<.+?>', ' ') INTO "stringa" FROM DUAL;
    select utl_i18n.unescape_reference("stringa") INTO v_return from dual;
    return (v_return);
END;
```

Comment: [The `unescape_reference` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_I18N.html#GUID-721DF8FD-2DBE-4CFD-BCDE-656242BD497E) take a varchar2 argument, not a CLOB. Does your HTML include line breaks with each line shorter than 4000 bytes - in which case you could chop it into individual lines, unescape those, and stick back together as a CLOB?

Comment: i can have spaces in html or maybe some <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. If you want to extract the text then use an XML parser:

```sql
SELECT a,
       b,
       c,
       UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(
         XMLQUERY(
           '//text()'
           PASSING XMLTYPE(blobfield, 1)
           RETURNING CONTENT
         ).getStringVal()
       ) AS text
FROM   t1
```

Which will work where the extracted text is 4000 characters or less (since `XMLTYPE.getStringVal()` will return a `VARCHAR2` data type and `UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE` accepts a `VARCHAR2` argument).

---

If you want to get it to work on `CLOB` values then you can still use `XMLQUERY` and  `getClobVal()` but  `UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE` still only works on `VARCHAR2` input (and not `CLOB`s) so you will need to split the `CLOB` into segments and parse those and concatenate them once you are done.

Something like:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION html_to_text(
  i_xml IN XMLTYPE
) RETURN CLOB
IS
  v_text   CLOB;
  v_output CLOB;
  str      VARCHAR2(4000);
  len      PLS_INTEGER;
  pos      PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  lim      CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 4000;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLQUERY(
           '//text()'
           PASSING i_xml
           RETURNING CONTENT
         ).getStringVal()
  INTO   v_text
  FROM   DUAL;
  
  len := LENGTH(v_text);
  WHILE pos <= len LOOP
    str := DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(v_text, lim, pos);
    v_output := v_output || UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(str);
    pos := pos + lim;
  END LOOP;
  
  RETURN v_output;
END;
/
```

However, you probably want to make it more robust and check if you are going to split the string in the middle of an escaped XML character.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=db7c3a9b7735f93c6ed03a8dd375f42a)*

Comment: found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53914336/replace-special-xml-characters-in-pl-sql to split but give me some error: link stringBuffer undeclared and then "numeric or value error)

Comment: got ORA-06553: PLS-307: too many declarations of 'XMLTYPE' match this call
06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s". it's because i have clob while you use blob field for table

Comment: found  XMLTYPE.createXML but not working on my text since is not correct xml: may have only plain text without any tag

Comment: @gt.guybrush Then add a tag to make it valid XML: `'<root>' || :your_string || '</root>'`